# Find shortest subsequence

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, sequence

We will deal with arrays of chars, but not strings!
Let we have the next three arrays:

```
{"c", "o", "m", "b", "i", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"},
{"i", "n", "t", "e", "r", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "a", "l"}, 
{"n", "o", "t", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}
```

and the target array

```
target = {"n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}
```

I need to find *shortest occurrence (and position) of target in every array as a sequence, maybe alternate with other chars*.
The next pattern is created:

```
pat = Riffle[ target,  ___ ]
```

It works well for the first and the last arrays:

```
SequencePosition[{"c", "o", "m", "b", "i", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}, pat] → {{6,11}}
SequencePosition[{"n", "o", "t", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}, pat] → {{1, 8}}
```

But for the second array two occurrences are found:

```
SequencePosition[{"i", "n", "t", "e", "r", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "a", "l"}, pat] → {{2, 11}, {6, 11}}
```

Manually I can select the last as shortest, but it's not possible in a real task.
So I tried this:

```
pat2 = Riffle[str, Shortest@x___ ]
```

It works good for the second:

```
SequencePosition[{"i", "n", "t", "e", "r", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "a", "l"}, pat2] → {{6, 11}}
```

but not work at all for the last:

```
SequencePosition[{"n", "o", "t", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}, pat2] → {}
```

So i'm very confused

Comment: Have you looked at `SequenceAlignment`? E.g., `SequenceAlignment[Characters @ "notation", Characters @ "nation"]`

Comment: maybe `ssp = First@*MaximalBy[Apply@Subtract]@*SequencePosition` used as `ssp[list1, pat]`?

Comment: btw, `pat2` says letters of `target` are separated by the _**same**_  sub-pattern.

Comment: @kglr, yes, thank you, `x___` is bad idea!

Comment: @CarlWoll, to my shame I didn’t know `SequenceAlignment` 
Now try it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### SequencePosition

```
ClearAll[shortestSequencePosition]

shortestSequencePosition = First @* MinimalBy[Differences] @* SequencePosition;
```

***Examples:***

```
{l1, l2, l3, l4, l5} = Characters @
 {"combination", "international","notation",
  "internationaln" <> StringJoin[ConstantArray["x", 100]] <> "ational",
  "intern" <> StringJoin[ConstantArray["x", 100]] <> "ationalnational"};

pat = Riffle[{"n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}, ___];

shortestSequencePosition[#, pat, Overlaps -> All] & /@ {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5}
```

> ```
> {{6, 11}, {6, 11}, {1, 8}, {6, 11}, {114, 119}}
> ```

#### ReplaceList

```
shortestSeqPos = First @ ReplaceList[#,
   {a___,  b : Shortest[PatternSequence @@ #2], ___} :> 
    {1 + Length[{a}], Length@{a, b}}, 1] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
shortestSeqPos[#, pat] & /@ {l1, l2, l3, l4, l5}
```

> ```
>  {{6, 11}, {6, 11}, {1, 8}, {6, 11}, {114, 119}}
> ```

Comment: Consider `shortestSequencePosition = Last @* SequencePosition;`?

Comment: @creidhne, that does not give the correct answer for cases like `l4 = Characters[
  "internationaln" <> StringJoin[ConstantArray["x", 20]] <> "ational"]`

Comment: I was about to remark that `shortestSequencePosition[#, pat]& /@ {l4} == {Last[SequencePosition[l4, pat]]}`, before your `Overlaps` revision. Good test case.

Comment: @kglr  Thank you! But I wonder is it possible to use `LongestCommonSequencePositions`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a bit of a hack. We may calculate the length of the matched pieces by:

```
Subtract @@@ (t = SequencePosition[data, pat])
```

where data is the character list and pat the pattern from above. Note we stored the differences, for later use, in t. Now we can get the order of the length and take the index of the shortest by:

```
Ordering[t][[-1]]
```

Finally, we may use the this index to get the shortest:

```
Subtract @@@ (t = SequencePosition[data, pat])[[Ordering[t][[-1]]]]
```

With this:

```
d1 = {"c", "o", "m", "b", "i", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"}; 
d2 = {"i", "n", "t", "e", "r", "n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n", "a", "l"}; 
d3 = {"n", "o", "t", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"};
target = {"n", "a", "t", "i", "o", "n"};
pat = Riffle[target, ___];

Subtract @@@ (t = SequencePosition[d1, pat])[[Ordering[t][[-1]]]]
Subtract @@@ (t = SequencePosition[d2, pat])[[Ordering[t][[-1]]]]
Subtract @@@ (t = SequencePosition[d3, pat])[[Ordering[t][[-1]]]]

{6, 11}
{6, 11}
{1, 8}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

In a comment, kglr suggested an important test case. His improved solution adds the `Overlaps -> All` to `SequencePosition`. The `Overlaps` option is necessary to include overlapping ranges; the change means we can't rely on the last `SequencePosition` result to be the shortest. I've added the test case and implemented kglr's revised solution.

---

First, set `target` and `pat` from your question. Next, create a [regular expression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) pattern from the target characters. Use `regex` to get a list of words that we can use for testing.

```
target = Characters["nation"];
pat = Riffle[target, ___];

regex = RegularExpression[StringRiffle[target, {"^.*", ".*", ".*$"}]];
words = DeleteDuplicates[ToLowerCase[DictionaryLookup[regex, IgnoreCase -> True]]];
```

**Problem:**

1. When there is no matching pattern of characters in a sequence, `SequencePosition` returns an empty list.
2. Some sequences match `pat` in more than one range of positions. We want the shortest range, e.g., we want to select `{6, 11}` and reject `{2, 11}`.

Sequences like `noNationMatch` cause a problem when we try to find the shortest character range.

```
noNationMatch = Characters["regurgitation"];
SequencePosition[noNationMatch, pat]
(* {} *)
```

I suggest that `pat` is an efficient way to match character ranges, but we first must eliminate sequences with no possibility for a match. For example, consider these test cases. Use `regex` to reject "regurgitation". We'll use the list of sequences `seq` to check each sequence in a table.

```
testCases = {"regurgitation", "combination", "international", "notation",
  "tintinnabulation", "interdenominational",
  "internationalnxxxxxxxxxxational"};
Column[seq = Characters/@Select[seqList, StringMatchQ[regex]]]
```

```
{"c","o","m","b","i","n","a","t","i","o","n"},
{"i","n","t","e","r","n","a","t","i","o","n","a","l"},
{"n","o","t","a","t","i","o","n"},
{"t","i","n","t","i","n","n","a","b","u","l","a","t","i","o","n"},
{"i","n","t","e","r","d","e","n","o","m","i","n","a","t","i","o","n","a","l"},
{"i","n","t","e","r","n","a","t","i","o","n","a","l","n","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","a","t","i","o","n","a","l"}
```

These are the ranges we find by matching `pat` with `SequencePosition`.

```
Table[
    DeleteDuplicates[SequencePosition[s, pat, Overlaps -> All]],
  {s, seq}]//Column
```

```
{{6,11}},
{{2,11}, {6,11}},
{{1,8}},
{{3,16}, {6,16}, {7,16}},
{{2,17}, {8,17}, {12,17}},
{{2,29}, {2,14}, {2,11}, {6,29}, {6,14}, {6,11}, {11,29}, {14,29}}
```

Find the shortest of the ranges.

```
Table[
    First[MinimalBy[SequencePosition[s, pat, Overlaps -> All], Differences]],
  {s, seq}]
```

```
{{6,11}, {6,11}, {1,8}, {7,16}, {12,17}, {6,11}}
```

Let's make a way to illustrate the ranges we find. Each result shows the range of characters, the sequence of matching characters, and the highlighted characters in the sequence we tested. We can verify that we've matched the shortest range of characters.

```
Clear[highlight];
SetAttributes[highlight, HoldAll];
highlight[pattern_, style_] :=
  s_String :> (Row[{##}]&@@StringReplace[s, t:pattern :> style[t]])
```

```
TableForm[Table[{
    p = First@MinimalBy[SequencePosition[s, pat, Overlaps -> All], Differences],
    StringJoin@Take[s, p],
    StringJoin[s] /. highlight[StringJoin@Take[s, p], Style[#, Red] &]},
  {s, seq}], TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image: matching sequences]

**Testing**

Make sequences from words that match 2 or more ranges.

```
mp = Cases[words, w_ /; Length[SequencePosition[Characters[w], pat]] >= 2];
seq = Characters/@mp;
TableForm[Table[{
    p = First@MinimalBy[SequencePosition[s, pat, Overlaps -> All], Differences],
    StringJoin@Take[s, p],
    StringJoin[s] /. highlight[StringJoin@Take[s, p], Style[#, Red] &]},
  {s, seq}], TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image: matching sequences for multiple ranges]

Make sequences from a sample of words that match exactly one range.

```
SeedRandom[123];
sp = Sort@RandomSample[
  Cases[words, w_ /; Length[SequencePosition[Characters[w], pat]] == 1], 50];
seq = Characters/@sp;
TableForm[Table[{
  p = First@MinimalBy[SequencePosition[s, pat, Overlaps -> All], Differences],
  StringJoin@Take[s, p],
    StringJoin[s] /. highlight[StringJoin@Take[s, p], Style[#, Red] &]},
  {s, seq}], TableDepth -> 2]
```

[image: sequences with one range]